# How to pass colors as props to a linear gradient background property in styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

This is what my component looks like I can't figure out the syntax to pass the colors as props the background property. Thanks for having a look

```
  const CustomButton = styled.button`
   // other attributes
   height:${(props) => props.height || "40px"};
   background:linear-gradient(322.24deg, #60D9FF -4.38%, #1D74FF 48.84%);
  `
```

Comment: You want pass only ` #60D9FF` or all colors or all string `linear-gradient(322.24deg, #60D9FF -4.38%, #1D74FF 48.84%)`?

Comment: I would like  pass #60D9FF as a string props.color1 and #1D74FF props.color2

Comment: I saw the link updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
background:linear-gradient(322.24deg,${props => props.color1} -4.38%, 
${props => props.color2} 48.84%);
```